# box-shadow cut off when using column-count

Tags: css, flexbox, css-multicolumn-layout

I need to order my items from top-to-bottom, then left-to-right, e.g.:

```
1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
```

However, box shadow is being cutoff. Reference the snippet: item 3's box shadow is cut off at bottom and item 4 is cut off at the top (in chrome).

There are similar questions to this, however the answers don't apply in this situation. I can't use flex on the container with `flex-direction: column` as this requires an explicit height and my `item` count is dynamic. I also can't set the items to `display: inline-block` as other answers suggest, since I need to control this content with flex.

```css
.container {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 16px;
  width: 500px;
}

.item {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  height: 64px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

Two other things I've tried from other similar SO questions that did not work: setting `overflow: visible`, adding a wrapper around the items with transparent border. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `display: inline-flex` and `width: 100%` properties. `break-inside: avoid-column` property is invalid.

```css
.container {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 16px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-bottom: -14px;
}

.item {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  height: 64px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this did fix the box-shadow on the bottom of item3, but item4 is still cut off at the top for me

Comment: Quick hack to fix this issue on Chrome would be adding 2px top margin to blocks.

Comment: cool thanks. I have adjusted the .item margins to be `margin-top: 2px`, `margin-bottom: 14px` to maintain the 16px total margin, and then setting `margin-top: -2px` on the container to preserve the spacing there as well. I think this will work unless im missing something!

Answer (score 3):

An idea is to use a pseudo-element where you apply the box-shadow. Make sure the pseudo element doesn't span all the space so it won't get affected by the cutting (use `top` and `bottom` different from 0)

```css
.container {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 16px;
  width: 500px;
}

.item {
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  height: 64px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.item:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:1px;
  bottom:3px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
    box-shadow: 
   0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 
   0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 
   0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: interesting solution!